# First vagrant up fails

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, varying

I'm trying to get vvv up and running in order to work on a wordpress site, and while following the "First Vagrant Up" instructions my installation fails.  You can find the terminal output below.

Just to note, the `vagrant up` command below is run as sudo, but I get the same result when running it without.

https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/tree/master#the-first-vagrant-up

My installation fails at step 8

```
doug@UNEMAC06261 vagrant-local$ sudo vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant-local_default_1411438722704_61758
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  vvv  # VAGRANT: 5060d38a36f5e1f12d46263feb41f99a (default) / 502bc2fa-8395-48b4-a09c-09aa74586389
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  vvv.dev  # VAGRANT: 5060d38a36f5e1f12d46263feb41f99a (default) / 502bc2fa-8395-48b4-a09c-09aa74586389
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  local.wordpress.dev  # VAGRANT: 5060d38a36f5e1f12d46263feb41f99a (default) / 502bc2fa-8395-48b4-a09c-09aa74586389
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  local.wordpress-trunk.dev  # VAGRANT: 5060d38a36f5e1f12d46263feb41f99a (default) / 502bc2fa-8395-48b4-a09c-09aa74586389
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  src.wordpress-develop.dev  # VAGRANT: 5060d38a36f5e1f12d46263feb41f99a (default) / 502bc2fa-8395-48b4-a09c-09aa74586389
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.50.4  build.wordpress-develop.dev  # VAGRANT: 5060d38a36f5e1f12d46263feb41f99a (default) / 502bc2fa-8395-48b4-a09c-09aa74586389
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/doug/WebsitesNoMamp/vagrant-local
    default: /srv/www => /Users/doug/WebsitesNoMamp/vagrant-local/www
    default: /srv/log => /Users/doug/WebsitesNoMamp/vagrant-local/log
    default: /srv/config => /Users/doug/WebsitesNoMamp/vagrant-local/config
    default: /srv/database => /Users/doug/WebsitesNoMamp/vagrant-local/database
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20140922-5634-vig5ba.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Check for apt packages to install...
==> default:  * php5-fpm [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-cli [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-common [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-dev [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-memcache [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-imagick [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-mcrypt [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-mysql [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-imap [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-curl [not installed]
==> default:  * php-pear [not installed]
==> default:  * php5-gd [not installed]
==> default:  * nginx [not installed]
==> default:  * memcached [not installed]
==> default:  * mysql-server [not installed]
==> default:  * imagemagick [not installed]
==> default:  * subversion [not installed]
==> default:  * git-core [not installed]
==> default:  * zip [not installed]
==> default:  * unzip [not installed]
==> default:  * ngrep [not installed]
==> default:  * curl                                                7.35.0-1ubuntu2.1
==> default:  * make                                                3.81-8.2ubuntu3
==> default:  * vim                                                 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3
==> default:  * colordiff [not installed]
==> default:  * postfix [not installed]
==> default:  * gettext [not installed]
==> default:  * graphviz [not installed]
==> default:  * dos2unix [not installed]
==> default:  * g++ [not installed]
==> default:  * nodejs [not installed]
==> default: Linked custom apt sources
==> default: No network connection available, skipping package installation
==> default: Generate Nginx server private key...
==> default: /etc/nginx/server.key: No such file or directory 140344758421152:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/nginx/server.key','w') 140344758421152:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
==> default: Generate Certificate Signing Request (CSR)...
==> default: Error opening Private Key /etc/nginx/server.key
==> default: 140567930091168:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/nginx/server.key','r')
==> default: 140567930091168:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
==> default: unable to load Private Key
==> default: Sign the certificate using the above private key and CSR...
==> default: /etc/nginx/server.csr: No such file or directory
==> default: Setup configuration files...
==> default:  * /srv/config/init/vvv-start.conf               -> /etc/init/vvv-start.conf
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/nginx/nginx-wp-common.conf'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: mkdir: 
==> default: cannot create directory '/etc/nginx/custom-sites/'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: sending incremental file list
==> default: rsync: mkdir "/etc/nginx/custom-sites" failed: No such file or directory (2)
==> default: rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674) [Receiver=3.1.0]
==> default:  * /srv/config/nginx-config/nginx.conf           -> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
==> default:  * /srv/config/nginx-config/nginx-wp-common.conf -> /etc/nginx/nginx-wp-common.conf
==> default:  * /srv/config/nginx-config/sites/               -> /etc/nginx/custom-sites
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/php5/fpm/php5-fpm.conf'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/php-custom.ini'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/opcache.ini'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: sed: can't read /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini: No such file or directory
==> default:  * /srv/config/php5-fpm-config/php5-fpm.conf     -> /etc/php5/fpm/php5-fpm.conf
==> default:  * /srv/config/php5-fpm-config/www.conf          -> /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
==> default:  * /srv/config/php5-fpm-config/php-custom.ini    -> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/php-custom.ini
==> default:  * /srv/config/php5-fpm-config/opcache.ini       -> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/opcache.ini
==> default:  * /srv/config/php5-fpm-config/xdebug.ini        -> /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
==> default:  * /srv/config/memcached-config/memcached.conf   -> /etc/memcached.conf
==> default: sending incremental file list
==> default: db_backup
==> default: develop_git
==> default: makepot
==> default: vagrant_destroy
==> default: vagrant_halt
==> default: vagrant_suspend
==> default: xdebug_off
==> default: xdebug_on
==> default: sent 2.22K bytes  received 168 bytes  4.78K bytes/sec
==> default: total size is 3.00K  speedup is 1.25
==> default:  * /srv/config/bash_profile                      -> /home/vagrant/.bash_profile
==> default:  * /srv/config/bash_aliases                      -> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
==> default:  * /srv/config/vimrc                             -> /home/vagrant/.vimrc
==> default:  * /srv/config/subversion-servers                -> /home/vagrant/.subversion/servers
==> default:  * /srv/config/homebin                           -> /home/vagrant/bin
==> default: Restart services...
==> default: nginx: unrecognized service
==> default: memcached: unrecognized service
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 318: php5dismod: command not found
==> default: php5-fpm: unrecognized service
==> default: mysql: unrecognized service
==> default: Setup MySQL configuration file links...
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot create regular file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default:  * /srv/config/mysql-config/my.cnf               -> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
==> default:  * /srv/config/mysql-config/root-my.cnf          -> /home/vagrant/.my.cnf
==> default: service mysql restart
==> default: mysql: unrecognized service
==> default: No custom MySQL scripting found in database/init-custom.sql, skipping...
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 357: mysql: command not found
==> default: Initial MySQL prep...
==> default: Start MySQL Database Import
==> default: No custom databases to import
==> default: No network available, skipping network installations
==> default: find: 
==> default: `/etc/nginx/custom-sites'
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: Restart Nginx...
==> default: nginx: unrecognized service
==> default: Cleaning the virtual machine's /etc/hosts file...
==> default: Adding domains to the virtual machine's /etc/hosts file...
==> default:  * Added vvv.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added local.wordpress.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added local.wordpress-trunk.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added src.wordpress-develop.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added build.wordpress-develop.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default: -----------------------------
==> default: Provisioning complete in 32 seconds
==> default: No external network available. Package installation and maintenance skipped.
==> default: For further setup instructions, visit http://vvv.dev
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: mysql: unrecognized service
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Update:

It turns out that, for some reason, the only way to resolve the issue of not even being able to connect to the VM is to manually ssh into the server with `vagrant ssh` and manually install the software that it said that it was missing by running the following commands (in this instance):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
sudo apt-get install php5-common
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo apt-get install php5-memcache
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install memcached
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install subversion
sudo apt-get install git-core
sudo apt-get install zip
sudo apt-get install unzip
sudo apt-get install ngrep
sudo apt-get install colordiff
sudo apt-get install postfix
sudo apt-get install gettext
sudo apt-get install graphviz
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This did not fix the problem of actually being able to view my site on the VM.  Even though everything is now installed, I still cannot view the actual site which seems to me that the VM is not properly configured, and the configuration should happen automatically when I run `vagrant up`, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason I was not able to fully install the VM through vagrant is because the provision would fail.  During the provision process, it checks to see if you can ping a certain IP address, in this case 8.8.4.4.  On a normal network it should work, but on mine pinging is disabled, therefore this would return a false negative for a ping result even though there is network connectivity.

To fix the issue for me, I had to change the if statement that checked for the ping.

`if [[ $ping_result == *bytes?from* ]]; then`

becomes

`if [[ 1==1 ]]; then`

on line 136 https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/blob/master/provision/provision.sh#L136

and line 614 https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/blob/master/provision/provision.sh#L614

This is not a permanant fix, but it works for me in this case.

Comment: To check the status of the issue, you can check https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/pull/428

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your VM ins't able to access the network. What is the ip and subnet mask of your local network? https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV#caveats

Comment: The ip range of the network i'm running at home is 192.168.0.x.  Wouldn't it be better to assign it to that network?

Comment: You don't want the same network or you may cause yourself issues. Your host system is acting as a router for the VM) In fact if your subnet mask is 255.255.0.0 this may be the cause of your issue. Follow the instructions and change to a 172.16.x.x or a 10.x.x.x for the VM and see if that resolves your issue. (

Comment: Subnet is 255.255.255.0

Comment: I've determined that connecting to the VM is not an issue, it's the configuration of the VM that is the problem.

Comment: you may need to force a provision so 'vagrant up --provision' or 'vagrant provision'

Comment: Hum... What is the result you are getting at this point? You might want to try a 'vagrant destroy' and follow that with a 'vagrant up' that will rebuild everything.

Comment: I've destroyed the VM multiple times, all with the same result